# Drawing a moving average-style line representing the amount of quota left (R graph drawing)

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2

**2nd Edit** I now realise my revised code is close, but not quite there; it should only reasonably calculate the remaining daily average *where I have data*, not continually increase until the end of the month (i.e. it should be horizontal after the 20th).

**Edit**: I've now worked out how to include the "daily average remaining" (after much googling I found "within"). I'm just struggling getting the line to draw. New code:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("sitools")

Host=c("red", "blue", "green")
finish=as.Date("2015-04-30")
start=as.Date("2015-04-01")
Date=rep(seq(start, finish, "days"), each=3)
Bytes=c(sample(1e7:2e8, 60), rep(0, 30))
download = data.frame(Bytes, Date, Host)
download=within(download, days_remain <- as.numeric((finish - Date), units="days"))
download=within(download, avg_remain <- ((8e9 - cumsum(Bytes))/days_remain))
ggplot(download, aes(x = Date, y = Bytes, fill = Host)) + plot(download$Date, download$avg_remain) + geom_area() + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") +  scale_y_continuous("download", labels=f2si)
```

I'll leave the below in for context:

I'm drawing a graph of the usage of my ISP's monthly download quota, categorized by the host that uses it. I've got that part working quite well. What I'm struggling to do is to include a line which shows the average download available *per day* as calculated by subtracting the total usage.

I think it will look similar to a moving average graph, but it won't be related. I don't know of the correct term to search for, nor can I make the code work because I'm not good enough at R.

Here's an example which shows random data, grouped by three hosts (red, green, and blue), for the month of April 2015. It assumes that the data stops on the 20th. There's a horizontal line plotted at a magic number which represents the average allowance assuming constant usage. I want this line to move based on the cumulative usage.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("sitools")

Host=c("red", "blue", "green")
Date=rep(seq(as.Date("2015-04-01"), as.Date("2015-04-30"), "days"), each=3)
Bytes=c(sample(1e7:5e7, 60), rep(0, 30))
download = data.frame(Bytes, Date, Host)

ggplot(download, aes(x = Date, y = Bytes, fill = Host)) + geom_hline(yintercept=285000000) + geom_area() + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") +  scale_y_continuous("download", labels=f2si)
```

Ideally, that black line should change based on whether we've gone over or under our "daily average limit", giving an easy view of how much quota per day we've got left.

I've tried creating a for() loop which calculates total cumulative usage, then subtracting it from the total quota (8 GiBytes), but I couldn't work out how to put that vector(?) back into the ggplot *and* have it plotted as a magic black line on the same graph.

Any ideas how I can get the "daily limit" line on the graph?

Answer (score 1):

@Andy-w Thanks. I think you slightly misunderstood what I wanted, but that's probably my poor explanation. Your code allowed me to get what I wanted, mainly because yours worked!

```
library("ggplot2")

Host=c("red", "blue", "green")
finish=as.Date("2015-04-30")
start=as.Date("2015-04-01")
Date=rep(seq(start, finish, "days"), each=3)
Bytes=c(sample(1e7:2e8, 60), rep(0, 30))
download = data.frame(Bytes, Date, Host)
avg_remain=aggregate(Bytes ~ Date, download, sum)
avg_remain=within(avg_remain,  days_remain <- as.numeric((finish - Date), units="days"))
avg_remain=within(avg_remain, per_day <- (8e9 - cumsum(Bytes))/days_remain)

p = ggplot(download, aes(x = Date, y = Bytes)) + geom_area(aes(fill=Host)) + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") +  scale_y_continuous("download")
p2 = p + geom_line(data=avg_remain, aes(x=Date, y = per_day))
```

gives:

[image]

Again, thanks very much.

Comment: There you go with the image. I slightly updated the code (no need for the `sitools` library).

Comment: @andy-w Thanks again; the reason for the sitools library is to show figures as e.g. kilobytes/megabytes rather than in scientific notation.

Answer (score 0):

What I do here is to make a completely separate dataframe of the averages, and then add that to the plot.

```
library("ggplot2")

Host=c("red", "blue", "green")
Date=rep(seq(as.Date("2015-04-01"), as.Date("2015-04-30"), "days"), each=3)
Bytes=c(sample(1e7:5e7, 60), rep(0, 30))
download = data.frame(Bytes, Date, Host)

#note this is slightly different than original
p <- ggplot(download, aes(x = Date, y = Bytes)) + geom_hline(yintercept=285000000) + geom_area(aes(fill=Host)) + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") + 
            scale_y_continuous("download")

tot <- aggregate(x=download$Bytes,by=list(as.factor(download$Date)),FUN=sum)
tot$leftover <- 285000000 - tot$x
tot$Date <- as.Date(tot$Group.1)

p2 <- p + geom_line(data=tot, aes(x = Date, y = leftover), color = "black")
p2
```

[image]